# Prove piecewise function is not primitivable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Prove the function $ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}  
\sin( \frac{1}{x}) , x \in \mathbb{R}^{*} \\
-\frac{1}{2}\quad, x=0
\end{array}\right. $ is not primitivable.

I know that the function is a Darboux function since it maps an interval to an interval, while also being discontinuous since the left and right side limits when $x $ is approaching 0 do not exist. I've little clue how to continue the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then$$h'(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-2x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$The function $h'$ has a primitive. And so does the function$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}-2x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$since it's continuous. But then the function$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$has a primitive $p_1$. Suppose that $f$ has a primitive $p_2$. Then$$(p_2-p_1)'(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\ne0\\\frac12&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$and, by the Darboux theorem, no such differentiable function exists.